# Upgrading routes in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Currently I have something like this:

```
  resources :books do
    collection do
      get 'search'
    end
  end
```

and my controller name is also "books" and I have a action method called "search" inside it

I would like that "get search" part to also be a resource, kind of like nested resources... but I don't want to break other peoples codes that are using the current route that this generate, so need to update it in a passive way!

Comment: Do you want something like `books/1/searches/1`? Which actions do you want the `searches` resource to be able to do? You need to be a little more clear about what the new paths should look like.

Comment: I want it to be "passive" so whatever path the old route is generating, I want the new one to generate the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use shallow routes nesting like:

```
resources :books , :shallow => true do
  resources :searches
end
```

Now you will get the following routes:

```
/books/1 => books_path(1)
/books/1/searches => books_searches_index_path(1)
/searches/2 => searches_path(2)
```

Similarly you can get separate routing for defined routes like:

```
get '(:books)/searches', :to => 'books#index'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
resources :books do
  collection do
    get 'search'
  end
  resources :searches
end
```

...if I'm understanding you correctly, that should be what you want. It won't break other routes, just add new ones.

---

Run `rake routes` to make sure you have all the routes you want/need.

Comment: what is that "resources :searches"  at the end for?

Comment: You said you wanted to add a resource for searches. This would make routes like `books/1/searches` and `books/3/searches/edit`, etc.

Comment: I'm really unclear what kind of routes you need. What you have already won't break anyone else's code. Can you give an example of new routes you need, if you need them?